# Pandas HDFStore duplicate items Error

Tags: pandas

Hello All and thanks in advance.

I'm trying to do a periodic storing of financial data to a database for later querying. I am using Pandas for almost all of the data coding. I want to append a dataframe I have created into an HDF database. I read the csv into a dataframe and index it by timestamp. and the DataFrame looks like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 900 entries, 1378400701110 to 1378410270251
Data columns (total 23 columns):
....
...Columns with numbers of non-null values....
.....
dtypes: float64(19), int64(4)

store = pd.HDFStore('store1.h5')
store.append('df', df)
print store

<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store1.h5
/df            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->900,ncols->23,indexers->[index])
```

But when I then try to do anything with store,

```
print store['df']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 289,  in          __getitem__
return self.get(key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 422, in get
return self._read_group(group)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 930, in                _read_group
return s.read(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3175, in read
mgr = BlockManager([block], [cols_, index_])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1007, in __init__
self._set_ref_locs(do_refs=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1117, in _set_ref_locs
"does not have _ref_locs set" % (block,labels))
AssertionError: cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block 
[FloatBlock:   [LastTrade, Bid1, Bid1Volume,....., Ask5Volume], 19 x 900, dtype float64] 
with duplicate items 
[Index([u'LastTrade', u'Bid1', u'Bid1Volume',..., u'Ask5Volume'], dtype=object)] 
does not have _ref_locs set
```

I guess I am doing something wrong with the index, I'm quite new at this and have little knowhow.

EDIT:

The data frame construction looks like:

```
columns = ['TimeStamp', 'LastTrade', 'Bid1', 'Bid1Volume', 'Bid1', 'Bid1Volume',    'Bid2', 'Bid2Volume', 'Bid3', 'Bid3Volume', 'Bid4', 'Bid4Volume', 
       'Bid5', 'Bid5Volume', 'Ask1', 'Ask1Volume', 'Ask2', 'Ask2Volume', 'Ask3', 'Ask3Volume', 'Ask4', 'Ask4Volume', 'Ask5', 'Ask5Volume']

df = pd.read_csv('/20130905.csv', names=columns, index_col=[0])
```

df.head() looks like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 1378400701110 to 1378400703105
Data columns (total 21 columns):
LastTrade     5  non-null values
Bid1          5  non-null values
Bid1Volume    5  non-null values
Bid1          5  non-null values
.................values
Ask4          5  non-null values
Ask4Volume    5  non-null values
dtypes: float64(17), int64(4)
```

There's too many columns for it to print out the contents. But for example:

```
print df['LastTrade'].iloc[10]
LastTrade    1.31202
Name: 1378400706093, dtype: float64
```

and Pandas version:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.12.0'
```

Any ideas would be thoroughly appreciated, thank you again.

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: can you show is df.head() as well

Comment: also show how you are creating this frame (the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have a duplicate 'Bid1' and 'Bid1Volume' columns?

Unrrelated, but you should also set the index to a datetime index

```
import pandas as pd
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='ms')
```

This is a bug, because the duplicate columns cross dtypes (not a big deal
but undetected).

Easiest just to not have duplicate columns.

Will be fixed in 0.13, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4768